# Ubuntu Hard drive Partition Setup?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

Hello Ubuntu Community,
    I have one question to a successful and smooth installation of Ubuntu 12.04 and up! Here are the specifications of my system,

-500gb hard drive
 -6 gb of RAM 
 -AMD Processor

I would like to have a / partition, home partition and a swap partition. I know this is a hard request. I know that your home partition should be 90 percent of hard drive space,  10% for / directory, and 5-7 for swap partition.

So what I am asking you Ubuntu community is,  What do you advice me or recommend to do a proper installation setup?
Thank You
Ron
P.s I also have a different hard drive, that has Windows 7! Windows 7 and Ubuntu system.

Comment: I *typically* throw 20 GB @ `/`, as much `/swap` as I have RAM, and the rest @ `/home` and it has been pretty good for years.

Comment: I have one question for you sir, I have an amd proceesor, do you think I should have ubuntu amd version 64bit. I am a 64 bit man!

Comment: Absolutely, go with 64 bit whenever you can. Being able to throw a larger instruction set at the CPU is usually a good thing and it's really mature these days as 64 bit has been common for nearly 10 years now.

Comment: I have a tested run of amd 64 bit, but it just uses the processor so much. Like 98% used for a single program or simple task. But you do have a point. I have one processor.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to eat a lot of CPU cycles with 1 CPU. Any modern OS is, for the most part. With 64 bit you'll at least be (hopefully) using those CPU cycles efficiently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31125/discussion-between-ronnie-marlow-and-kgiii).

Answer (score 1):

My personal configuration is as follows:

/dev/sda1 (ext4) mounted as / - Size 10GB (4.95 GB free)
/dev/sda2 (ext4) mounted as /home - Size 100GB
/dev/sda3 (swap) - Size 2GB (might be removed later - I never use swap)

Comment: I have used this setup since Hardy Heron and I've yet to run out of space for new versions of XUbuntu and whatever software I need for my usage.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your input! On your opinion, does Ubuntu have a default installation that takes in all the components during the installation phase. Because if Ubuntu os installation would have a less of an issue during the installation of the Ubuntu system setup. Thanks

Comment: Yes, XUbuntu has a default installation setup, but I find that one (from my memories of the last time I used defaults, long ago) did not create a separate home partition, so everything was lumped in together (making it more difficult to do a fresh install with each upgrade.  this is unacceptable as upgrading from one version to the next is not always reliable.  I insist on having the capability to do a fresh install at each version as it's more reliable.).

Comment: Good point sir. :)  It would be more logical if the xUbuntu system and Ubuntu Versions would give the user the home directory and / directory and maybe maybe a swap partition during setup. Because we user's need the home directory for accessing personal files. The / directory should have a limit during the whole time. What is the need of the swap partition? Because if this variable was removed. Ubuntu would have less issues for the user.

Comment: If the installation of Ubuntu and the other variable's of installation would only have,  / partition and the home partition are the only only two variables to worry about. The / partition would be invisible to the user, because it would only hold 10gb. The home partition is what the users prefer The average user would install it without regrets and issues during the installation phase.

Comment: The defaults do include a swap partition (again, based on memories that are years old here), but they don't separate root and home.  The swap partition is primarily for low-RAM machines but it's also used for hibernation (so if you want hibernate capability, you need a swap partition the same size as your RAM to ensure you can successfully dump to hibernation mode).  Otherwise, if you have ample RAM and no need for hiberation, there's no reason to have a swap partition on your system.