# how to install Ubuntu 14.03.4 LTS into laptop with windows xp

Tags: dual-boot

i am using windows XP in my laptop. i want to install Ubuntu 14.03.4 LTS in my laptop and use it in addition to my windows XP. after downloading Ubuntu 14.03.4 LTS onto my laptop, i can't install it because "this file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action, create an association in the folder options control panel". what this means and how to go about it?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Look at the initially system, first put in the ubuntu disk or usb in computer. Boot up from their. Then you'll see the installation of windows system partations. You need to add the ubuntu system, create the / directory, /home directory, and swap partation. Do you're research before doing any installation. Because the three partations/directory for ubuntu are really important.
 Here is my question toward your problem and my problems. The solution.

[Ubuntu Hard drive Partition Setup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694056/ubuntu-hard-drive-partition-setup/694060?noredirect=1#comment1014463_694060)

Do your research. Ubuntu's installation is important.
Ron